# remove suffix after concatenate python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this anndata obj:

```
ldata1x
ldata2x
ldata3x
ldata4x
```

and I would to concatenate them into one df.

```
ldata1x.obs.index
Index(['KO_d6_r1_AAACCGGCACCTCGCT-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCCGCAAGGATTA-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAACCGCGTTAGCTGA-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTGTTTGTC-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AACAGATAGCAGCTAT-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTTCAAGCA-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAATGCCTCCAATTAG-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCCGCACAGAAAC-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTCTAACAG-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAACCGCGTGTAACCA-1',
       ...
       'KO_d6_r1_TTTCACCCACTAAGTT-1', 'KO_d6_r1_TTTGAGTCACCAAAGG-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_TTTAGCTTCACTCGCT-1', 'KO_d6_r1_TTTAGGATCTATGACA-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_TTTGACTTCATGAAGG-1', 'KO_d6_r1_TTTCACCCAGCTTACA-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_TTTGCATTCCGGAACC-1', 'KO_d6_r1_TTTAGGATCTTGGATA-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_TTTGACCGTGCTTACT-1', 'KO_d6_r1_TTTGGTAAGTTGTCCC-1'],
      dtype='object', length=1628)
```

so I did:

## concatenate the df

```
ldata = ldata1x.concatenate([ldata2x, ldata3x, ldata4x])
```

but I obtain this df:

```
ldata.obs.index
Index(['KO_d6_r1_AAACCGGCACCTCGCT-1-0', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCCGCAAGGATTA-1-0',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAACCGCGTTAGCTGA-1-0', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTGTTTGTC-1-0',
       'KO_d6_r1_AACAGATAGCAGCTAT-1-0', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTTCAAGCA-1-0',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAATGCCTCCAATTAG-1-0', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCCGCACAGAAAC-1-0',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTCTAACAG-1-0', 'KO_d6_r1_AAACCGCGTGTAACCA-1-0',
       ...
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTCACCCACTTAACG-1-3', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGGCTGTAGGATCC-1-3',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTCTCACAATTGCGC-1-3', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGCATTCAATGTGC-1-3',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTCGTCCAAACAACA-1-3', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGCATTCCCTGGTT-1-3',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTGGCTGTGCATTTC-1-3', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGACTTCCGCTAGA-1-3',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTGTTGGTTCCTGTG-1-3', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGTTGGTGGAAGGC-1-3'],
      dtype='object', length=5536)
```

in other words I don't need the suffixes `-0, -1, -2, -3` (that identified the dataframes) after -1.
How can I remove them? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this to remove suffixes

```
# Remove the suffixes
def remove_suffix(string):
  return string.rsplit('-', 1)[0]

ldata.index = ldata.index.map(remove_suffix)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't do it *upstream*, since [`obs.index`](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/anndata.AnnData.obs_names.html#anndata.AnnData.obs_names) returns a [`pd.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) object, you can use [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.html) :

```
out = idx.str[:-2]

Index(['KO_d6_r1_AAACCGGCACCTCGCT-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCCGCAAGGATTA-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAACCGCGTTAGCTGA-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTGTTTGTC-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AACAGATAGCAGCTAT-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTTCAAGCA-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAATGCCTCCAATTAG-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCCGCACAGAAAC-1',
       'KO_d6_r1_AAAGCGGGTCTAACAG-1', 'KO_d6_r1_AAACCGCGTGTAACCA-1',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTCACCCACTTAACG-1', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGGCTGTAGGATCC-1',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTCTCACAATTGCGC-1', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGCATTCAATGTGC-1',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTCGTCCAAACAACA-1', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGCATTCCCTGGTT-1',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTGGCTGTGCATTTC-1', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGACTTCCGCTAGA-1',
       'KO_d8_r2_TTTGTTGGTTCCTGTG-1', 'KO_d8_r2_TTTGTTGGTGGAAGGC-1'],
      dtype='object')
```